# How to use Spotify Search Service in Xcode

Tags: spotify

I am new to Swift and the APK environment and currently the app loads a playlist that I have given it. But how can I have the user select a song from the Spotify Search Service and have the app play the single track instead of playing through a playlist?

project link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx-U3vtX9ZWDSGtXRFdBekpWZkE/view?usp=sharing